# Crossword code error

Tags: java

I'm doing a crossword program in Java and I'm stuck.

Whenever I try to execute the code like `java assign2 > input.txt`, nothing happens, it's like an infinite loop.

Granted that my crossword program is not complete it's just that if I can't test it I can't do anything else, here is my code if you can help.

```
import java.util.*;

public class A2
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String[] a = new String[100];
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String t = scanner.nextLine();
        Crossword cw = new Crossword(t);
        int count = 0;
        System.out.print("1");
        for (; !t.equals(""); count++)
        {
            System.out.print("2");
            a[count] = t;
            t = scanner.nextLine();
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < 20; k++)
                System.out.print(cw.crossword[j][k]);
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}

/**
   The class Crossword knows how to build a crossword layout from
   a list of words.
*/
class Crossword
{
    public char[][] crossword = new char[20][20];

    public Crossword(String first)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < first.length(); i++)
            crossword[9][i] = first.charAt(i);
    }
}
```

I'm about to give up at this point, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're writing to the same file you're reading from. You read from `"input.txt"` and you call your program with `java assign2 > input.txt` (or `java A2...`).

This means that, as you write to `System.out` which is redirected to `input.txt`, the file gets more lines to read from, and your condition `!t.equals("")` never becomes false.

Comment: Oh wait that's my mistake, its actually `Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);`

Comment: But then, with `System.in`, it doesn't seem to get stuck. It stops once I've entered an empty line.

Comment: Uhhh the program has to run with the command java A2 > input.txt, you dont type anything

Comment: If you were given input.txt as part of the assignment, and want to ingest it into your application as input, you probably want java A2 < input.txt (although your input.txt was probably wiped out by the >, so you may need to redownload it)

Comment: Oh yea you're right but then i get this error `Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
        at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1516)
        at A2.main(A2.java:21)
`

Comment: You might need an empty last line in input.txt.

Comment: Ty kyle and Vlad i can finally start this assignment :D

Answer (score 1):

I've given this a spin and it does appear to work - however, check the direction of the redirect on your file; I think you're after:

```
java assign2 < input.txt
```

It's not completely clear what you're trying to achieve in terms of output, but I suspect you need something closer to the following:

```
public class Main {
    private static Crossword[] crosswords = new Crossword[20];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        int index = 0;

        while (!line.equals("") && index < 20) {
            crosswords[index++] = new Crossword(line);
            line = scanner.nextLine();
        }

        for (int i=0; i < 20; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j < 20; j++) {
                if (crosswords[i] != null) {
                    System.out.print(crosswords[i].crossword[j]);                
                } else {
                    System.out.print("");                
                }
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.